# Is there a query to set a table's engine to innodb if it's not already?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engine

I can set a (MyISAM) table's engine to InnoDB using the query:

```
alter table tablename engine=InnoDB
```

which takes some time to complete for large tables. It appears though that if I run the same query again on the same table, it takes some time again (much less but still considerable). I would expect the query to be instantaneous, since the engine is already set to innodb.

My questions are:

- Is there a single query that conditionally sets the engine, for example

  alter table tablename engine=InnoDB <if not already innodb>
- Why does the second query have such a delay? (out of curiosity mostly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will mass convert all MyISAM tables to InnoDB

```
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB;')"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} table_schema NOT IN "
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} ORDER BY (data_length+index_length)"
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > ConvertMyISAMToInnoDB.sql
mysql -uroot -p -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > ConvertMyISAMToInnoDB.sql
mysql -uroot < ConvertMyISAMToInnoDB.sql
```

Why does running `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;` take long ?

Under the hood it runs something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytabletmp LIKE mydb.mytable;
INSERT INTO mydb.mytabletmp SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;
DROP TABLE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytabletmp RENAME mydb.mytable;
```

The delay comes when building a brand new [**Clustered Index (home of PRIMARY KEY entries)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html)

If you want to totally automate the conversion of just one table, you need this:

```
SET @mydb = 'mydb';
SET @mytb = 'mytable';
SET @newengine = 'InnoDB';
SELECT IF(dbtb2='.',CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',dbtb1,' ENGINE=InnoDB'),
CONCAT('SELECT ''',dbtb1,' is Already ',engine,''' as \"No Need to Convert\"'))
INTO @ConvertEngineSQL FROM (SELECT CONCAT(A.db,'.',A.tb) dbtb1,
CONCAT(IFNULL(B.db,''),'.',IFNULL(B.tb,'')) dbtb2,engine
FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb,engine FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema=@mydb and table_name=@mytb) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema=@mydb and table_name=@mytb AND engine=@newengine) B
USING (db,tb)) AA;
SELECT @ConvertEngineSQL;
PREPARE st FROM @ConvertEngineSQL; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
```

Here is a sample from my PC's MySQL setup

```
mysql> show create table codewaggle.mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @mydb = 'codewaggle';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @mytb = 'mytable';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @newengine = 'InnoDB';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(dbtb2='.',CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',dbtb1,' ENGINE=InnoDB'),
    -> CONCAT('SELECT ''',dbtb1,' is Already ',engine,''' as \"No Need to Convert\"'))
    -> INTO @ConvertEngineSQL
    -> FROM (SELECT CONCAT(A.db,'.',A.tb) dbtb1,
    -> CONCAT(IFNULL(B.db,''),'.',IFNULL(B.tb,'')) dbtb2,engine
    -> FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb,engine FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema=@mydb and table_name=@mytb) A LEFT JOIN
    -> (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema=@mydb and table_name=@mytb AND engine=@newengine) B
    -> USING (db,tb)) AA;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @ConvertEngineSQL;
+----------------------------------------------+
| @ConvertEngineSQL                            |
+----------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE codewaggle.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE st FROM @ConvertEngineSQL; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.70 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @mydb = 'codewaggle';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @mytb = 'mytable';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @newengine = 'InnoDB';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(dbtb2='.',CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',dbtb1,' ENGINE=InnoDB'),
    -> CONCAT('SELECT ''',dbtb1,' is Already ',engine,''' as \"No Need to Convert\"'))
    -> INTO @ConvertEngineSQL
    -> FROM (SELECT CONCAT(A.db,'.',A.tb) dbtb1,
    -> CONCAT(IFNULL(B.db,''),'.',IFNULL(B.tb,'')) dbtb2,engine
    -> FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb,engine FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema=@mydb and table_name=@mytb) A LEFT JOIN
    -> (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema=@mydb and table_name=@mytb AND engine=@newengine) B
    -> USING (db,tb)) AA;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @ConvertEngineSQL;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @ConvertEngineSQL                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT 'codewaggle.mytable is Already InnoDB' as "No Need to Convert" |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE st FROM @ConvertEngineSQL; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

+--------------------------------------+
| No Need to Convert                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| codewaggle.mytable is Already InnoDB |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: For example, I have a table with 500k entries (nothing fancy). Running the alter table ... engine=innodb takes approx. 47'' to complete. Running it again requires 40''. Shouldn't (or couldn't) mysql simply bypass the query since the table's engine is already innodb?

Comment: Updated my answer with a nice SQL script to convert the table or catch on it's already InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

> Running ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB on an existing InnoDB table
> performs a “null” ALTER TABLE operation, which can be used to
> defragment an InnoDB table, as described in Section 14.12.4,
> “Defragmenting a Table”. Running ALTER TABLE tbl_name FORCE on an
> InnoDB table performs the same function.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)